# Remove "All Apps" icon from Start Menu

Tags: windows, windows-10

In order for my kid to stop opening any apps, I created a Standard User account, logged into it and turned off the following:

> Personalize-->Start-->Show app list in Start menu

This did the trick but it also added the following the icon to the start menu which, when clicked, shows up all the apps again thereby defeating the purpose.

[image]

Is there a way to hide that icon as well? The purpose here is to not let the standard user see any icons on the start menu other than the power and log off options.

Comment: Downvoters, care to explain? Why is this not a legitimate question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1 of 2**

Step 1: Type Gpedit.msc in Start menu or taskbar search box and then press Enter key to open Local Group Policy Editor.

Step 2: In the Group Policy Editor, navigate to:

User Configuration > Administrative Templates > Start Menu and Taskbar

Step 3: Click on Start Menu and Taskbar to see all Start menu and taskbar related policies on the right-side.

Step 4: Look for the policy named Remove All Programs list from the Start menu, and double-click on the same to open its properties.

Step 5: Finally, select Enabled to remove All apps button from Start menu or select Not Configured to show All apps button in the Windows 10 Start button. Don’t forget to click the Apply button.

Step 6: Sign out and sign in or reboot your PC once to see the change. You can also restart File Explorer by opening Task Manager, right-clicking on Windows Explorer (under Processes tab), and then clicking Restart option to see the change.

**Method 2 of 2**

Add or remove All apps button using Registry

This method applies to all editions of Windows 10.

Step 1: Open Registry Editor. To do so, type Regedit in Start menu search box or taskbar search box and then press Enter key.

Click Yes button when you see the User Account Control prompt.

Step 2: Navigate to the following key in Registry Editor:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer

Step 3: Click on the Explorer key. On the right-side, right-click on the empty area, click New, click DWORD (32-bit) Value, and then name it as NoStartMenuMorePrograms.

Step 4: Finally, double-click on NoStartMenuMorePrograms and set its value data to 0 (zero) to show All apps button, and set the value to 1 (one) to hide All apps button in Windows 10 Start menu.

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work. The "All Apps" icon is still visible

Comment: I stand corrected. It worked. I don't know how but it's no longer visible.

Comment: Glad to hear it! Make sure to mark as solved or upvote or whatever :D

Comment: It's already marked as solved